# "User Authentication" Chome App Tutorial Page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Trying to follow this intro to user authentication using OAuth 2.0 in a Chrome Extension I am developing. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

But I can't follow it (missing information).

> **Add permissions and upload app**
> You need to make sure the identity permission is in your manifest. You can
> then upload your app to the apps and extensions management page (see Publish).

This step is fine. I have uploaded my project and it is in the developer dashboard.

> **Copy key to your manifest**
> When you register your application in the Google OAuth console, you'll provide your application's ID, which will be checked during token requests. Therefore it's important to have a consistent application ID during development.
>
> To keep your application ID constant, you need to copy the key in the installed manifest.json to your source manifest. It's not the most graceful task, but here's how it goes:
>
> 1.Go to your user data directory. Example on MacOs: ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions
>
> 2.List the installed apps and extensions and match your app ID on the apps and extensions management page to the same ID here.
>
> 3.Go to the installed app directory (this will be a version within the app ID).
>
> 4.Open the installed manifest.json (pico is a quick way to open the file).
>
> 5.Copy the "key" in the installed manifest.json and paste it into your app's source manifest file.

Except, straight away, at step 1, I cannot progress. My app is not installed and therefore its ID does not appear in the user data directory.

Will installing the unpacked extension work? Well it doesn't appear in Default/Extensions directory so I guess not. Besides, it has been given a different ID than my dashboard instance.

Therefore, where do I get the key? There is a key associated with my app on the developer dashboard. But this "tutorial" doesn't mention that.

Is somebody able to explain what I should be doing such as pointing me to another resource to learn how to set up a basic user authentication for a Chrome App?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I was able to download the packaged app from the developer dashboard after I uploaded it, then just looked at the id in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After uploading, from the [developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard?authuser=0) you can click on the "More Info" on the right of your extension in the dashboard.

You will see several pieces of useful data:

1. item id - this is the extension id
2. public key - this is the "key" you want.  Copy everything between (not including) the "BEGIN PUBLIC KEY" and "END PUBLIC KEY" markers, and paste it into a "key" property in your `manifest.json`

Comment: It seems likely that they added the 'more info' button after they wrote the tutorial. Both of these solutions work but the problem is with incomplete/old/redundant google documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve this:

> 1. In the Chrome Developer Dashboard, **edit** your current project.
> 2. Scroll down and click **Preview Changes**
> 3. Click the **Share** icon button next to Add To Chrome which is grayed out.
> 4. E-mail the link to yourself.
> 5. Follow the link to your app's store page and now you should be able to click **Add To Chrome**. It will then be installed on your system under [profile]/Extensions.